# TypeError: economico() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'carro' and 'consumo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-2.7

I have an assignment to turn in for the University. I already got the correct result in VS Code with the code below (the idea is to show the car with the lowest consumption):

```
def entrada_carro():
    carro = []
    for i in range(4):
        carro.append(input("Digite o modelo do carro: "))
    return carro

def entrada_consumo():
    consumo = []
    for i in range(4):
        consumo.append(int(input("Digite o consumo do carro: ")))
    return consumo

def economico(carro, consumo):
    menor = consumo[0]
    for i in range(1,4):
        if consumo[i] < menor:
            menor = consumo[i]
    return carro[consumo.index(menor)]

def main():
    carro = entrada_carro()
    consumo = entrada_consumo()
    print("O carro mais economico é o", economico(carro, consumo))

main()
```

Although it works. The university platform uses another main() function already, which is as follows (there is a particularity, to send on the platform I cannot have the texts inside the inputs, which does not influence; I just remove those before sending):

```
def main():
    entrada_carro()
    entrada_consumo()
    print(economico())
    
main()
```

So, I just need to send all the other three functions.

And the error only occurs when I play this in the validator (the code without the part that the platform already has). Test entries are as follows:

1. (result must be AUDI): JEEP AUDI BMW JAGUAR 10 6 8 12 2. (result must be UP): CELTA GOL UP KA 10 7 6 9

The result with the error: [image: Error img]

The article ahead didn't help me (only if I didn't understand if the answer is there): [how to resolve missing 2 required positional argument python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390052/como-resolver-missing-2-required-positional-argument-python).

Can anyone help understand please? Thanks in advance!!

I have checked that there are differences between my main() and Uni's:

Mine (with declared variables):

```
def main():
    carro = entrada_carro()
    consumo = entrada_consumo()
    print("O carro mais economico é o", economico(carro, consumo))

main()
```

And theirs (without variables declared):

```
def main():
    entrada_carro()
    entrada_consumo()
    print(economico())
    
main()
```

I just don't understand the implications...

Comment: You've defined a function `economico(carro, consumo)` to require two parameters and are trying to call it with zero parameters (`economico()`).

Comment: Some text are in PT-BR:

carro = car
consumo = consumption
entrada = input

"O carro mais economico é o" = "The most economic car is"

"Digite o modelo do carro: " = "Type the car model: "

"Digite o consumo do carro: " = "Type car's consumption"

Comment: Mmm, I see @AKX... but that bit is from Uni's code, so how would I be able to not define in that manner and still make it work? (because I cannot change their main() function)... Do you have ideas?

Comment: After refreshing the page I saw your answer hahaha; much appreciated, bro! You rock! I have around 3+ min until able to accept your answer (not sure why), then I'll do so! All the best!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined a function `economico(carro, consumo)` to require two parameters and that `main` is trying to call it with zero parameters (`economico()`).

If you can't change the `main` invocation run by your uni's test harness, you'll need to change your functions to read and write
`consumo` and `carro` as globals instead of return values (ick)...

```
consumo = []
carro = []


def entrada_carro():
    for i in range(4):
        carro.append(input("Digite o modelo do carro: "))


def entrada_consumo():
    for i in range(4):
        consumo.append(int(input("Digite o consumo do carro: ")))


def economico():
    menor = consumo[0]
    for i in range(1,4):
        if consumo[i] < menor:
            menor = consumo[i]
    return carro[consumo.index(menor)]
```

Comment: Much appreciated, @AKX! Fast as lightning and totally assertive!